# Adding a font to X11 XLoadQueryFont

Tags: x11, fonts

I'm trying to use an old binary (HP VEX simulator: http://www.hpl.hp.com/downloads/vex) which uses VCG visualization tool (http://www.rw.cdl.uni-saarland.de/~sander/html/gsvcg1.html) on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS.

I cannot produce any graphical output because of the function call `XLoadQueryFont` returns false when trying to load courier font. Here are some snippets from the source code:

```
#define VCG_DEFAULT_FONT "-*-courier-*-*-*--14-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"
char Xfontname[512] = VCG_DEFAULT_FONT;
panel_font = XLoadQueryFont(root_display,Xfontname);
if (!panel_font)
Fatal_error("Font not found.","");
```

I tried adding the courier font to my X11 fonts to solve this issue but I can't manage to figure it out. I got courier regular from http://fontsgeek.com/fonts/Courier-Regular/download and add it to `~/.fonts` but that didn't solve the issue.

I tried following http://vietunicode.sourceforge.net/howto/fontlinux.html and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Fonts but it still doesn't work.

Also it's interesting that running `xlsfonts` returns a courier font but with size 10, not 14, which probably doesn't match the one in the source code.

```
# xlsfonts | grep courier
-bitstream-courier 10 pitch-bold-i-normal--0-0-0-0-m-0-adobe-standard
-bitstream-courier 10 pitch-bold-i-normal--0-0-0-0-m-0-ascii-0
-bitstream-courier 10 pitch-bold-i-normal--0-0-0-0-m-0-iso10646-1
-bitstream-courier 10 pitch-bold-i-normal--0-0-0-0-m-0-iso8859-1
-bitstream-courier 10 pitch-bold-r-normal--0-0-0-0-m-0-adobe-standard
-bitstream-courier 10 pitch-bold-r-normal--0-0-0-0-m-0-ascii-0
-bitstream-courier 10 pitch-bold-r-normal--0-0-0-0-m-0-iso10646-1
-bitstream-courier 10 pitch-bold-r-normal--0-0-0-0-m-0-iso8859-1
-bitstream-courier 10 pitch-medium-i-normal--0-0-0-0-m-0-adobe-standard
-bitstream-courier 10 pitch-medium-i-normal--0-0-0-0-m-0-ascii-0
-bitstream-courier 10 pitch-medium-i-normal--0-0-0-0-m-0-iso10646-1
-bitstream-courier 10 pitch-medium-i-normal--0-0-0-0-m-0-iso8859-1
-bitstream-courier 10 pitch-medium-r-normal--0-0-0-0-m-0-adobe-standard
-bitstream-courier 10 pitch-medium-r-normal--0-0-0-0-m-0-ascii-0
-bitstream-courier 10 pitch-medium-r-normal--0-0-0-0-m-0-iso10646-1
-bitstream-courier 10 pitch-medium-r-normal--0-0-0-0-m-0-iso8859-1
```

Any idea what would be the right way to add `"-*-courier-*-*-*--14-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"` font to X11 so that it will be detected by `XLoadQueryFont`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way would be to install the [**`xfonts-75dpi`**](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfonts-75dpi) package, which has the pattern that you're looking for, e.g.,

```
-adobe-courier-medium-r-normal--14-100-100-100-m-90-iso10646-1
-adobe-courier-medium-r-normal--14-100-100-100-m-90-iso10646-1
-adobe-courier-medium-r-normal--14-100-100-100-m-90-iso8859-1
-adobe-courier-medium-r-normal--14-100-100-100-m-90-iso8859-1
-adobe-courier-medium-r-normal--14-140-75-75-m-90-iso10646-1
-adobe-courier-medium-r-normal--14-140-75-75-m-90-iso10646-1
-adobe-courier-medium-r-normal--14-140-75-75-m-90-iso8859-1
-adobe-courier-medium-r-normal--14-140-75-75-m-90-iso8859-1
```

That automatically updates the font-directory:

```
sudo apt-get install xfonts-75dpi
```